# Data sharding based on schemes in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant

I would like to develop a multi-tenant web application using PostgreSQL DB, having the data of each tenant in a dedicated scheme.
Each query or update will access only a single tenant scheme and/or the public scheme.

Assuming I will, at some point, need to scale out and have several PostgreSQL servers, is there some automatic way in which I can connect to a single load balancer of some sort, that will redirect the queries/updates to the relevant server, based on the required scheme?

Comment: I haven't used Pl/Proxy. But may be you will be able to do what you want to, with it. Please have a look http://plproxy.projects.pgfoundry.org/doc/faq.html

Comment: @Jayadevan, you are right, plproxy's solution of allowing me to write the logic for deciding which datanode to connect is exactly what I'm looking for. However, most of the code for the app I develop is inherited from an existing project, and it makes almost no use of DB functions. Since plproxy works _only_ with DB functions, choosing it would force me to make a tremendous change in the code, and this is not an option currently. Thanks!

Comment: If you are OK with figuring out the database server the request should go to, based on the source machine IP, have a look at HAProxy http://serverfault.com/questions/502487/haproxy-load-balancing-based-on-source-ip-ip-subnet. I have used HAProxy for load balancing requests to MySQL server and found it to be pretty good. But that was a simple round robin redirect.

Comment: This does not suit my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenging part of this question is 'automatic way'. I have a feeling that postgres is moving that way, maybe 9.5 or later will have multi-master tendencies with partitioning allowing spreading of data across a cluster so that your frontend doesn't have to change.

Assuming that your tenants can operate in separate databases, and you are looking for a way to operate a query in the correct database, perhaps something like dns could be used during your connection to the database, using the tenant ID as a component in the dns host. Something like:

```
tenant_1.example.com -> 192.168.0.10
tenant_2.example.com -> 192.168.0.11
tenant_3.example.com -> 192.168.0.11
etc.example.com ->  192.168.0.X
```

Then you could use the connection as a map to the correct db installation. The tricky part here is the overlapping data that all tenants would need access to. If that overlapping data needs to be joined to then it will have to exist in all databases. Either copied or dblinked. If the overlapping data needs to be updated then automatic is going to be tough. Good question.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was hoping to find, but since there is no better answer, I'm accepting it. Thank you.

Comment: 9.5 alpha released a couple of weeks ago would support that without DNS trickery. Combine foreign tables with multiple sequences on the master and you effectively have sharding, though AFAICT you're still limited to a single master node. Maybe they'll get BDR finalized before 9.5 final, and then you could implement high-availability sharding.

Comment: i am very excited about the 9.5 release.  bdr is kind of there already, but, i don't think of it as multi-master yet.  i remember trying to do the partition thing with foreign tables many years ago. i think it will work now, but, i don't think there is parallel execution on queries, so you still have to serially go through all of the endpoints.  it is super close :-) you know, as long as all data is foreign there is nothing from keeping you from having multiple masters...hmm...